# Geometric argument showing that the sum of the series $\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} n^{-1}(n + 1)^{-1}$ is $1$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, problem-solving

[image]

I can't see the relationship between this telescopic series and the area under the curve for functions $f(x)=x^n$.

Comment: Perhaps they find it more intuitive that the area between the graphs of $f_n$ and $f_{n+1}$ is $\frac1{n(n+1)}$ than that the distance between the points $\frac 1n$ and $\frac1{n+1}$ is $\frac1{n(n+1)}$. The computation to show the former uses the latter fact, however

Answer (score 9):

Write out the partial sums of the series into a telescopic sum:
$$ s_n = \sum_{i=1}^n  \frac{1}{i} - \frac{1}{i+1}$$
from here we already see that
$$ s_n = 1 - \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{3} + \cdots + \frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{n+1} = 1 - \frac{1}{n+1}$$
Taking $n\to \infty$ we have that $s_n \to 1$... However, the question explicitly talks about *geometry*. Lets find out the areas of the functions $f_n(x) = x^n$:
$$\int _0^1 f_0(x)\mathrm d x = \int_0^1  \mathrm d x = 1$$
$$\int _0^1 f_1(x)\mathrm d x = \int_0^1 x \mathrm d x = \frac{1}{2}$$
$$\int _0^1 f_2(x)\mathrm d x = \int_0^1 x^2 \mathrm d x = \frac{1}{3}$$
$$\int _0^1 f_2(x)\mathrm d x = \int_0^1 x^3 \mathrm d x = \frac{1}{4}$$
$$\int _0^1 f_2(x)\mathrm d x = \int_0^1 x^4 \mathrm d x = \frac{1}{5}$$
Hmmmm... The first is the area under a straight line, the second is the area under a triangle,  the third is the area under a parabola, and so on:
in the general case
$$ \int _0^1 f_n(x) \mathrm d x = \int_0^1 x^n\mathrm d x= \frac{1}{n+1}$$

Here, I have plotted some of the functions
[image]

Now note that the $n$th term of the sum is the difference between the areas under curve $n$ and curve $n+1$. Below you see the areas represented in the first 4 terms
[image]

Keep adding areas that become smaller and smaller and you will have a full square with side 1 and area 1 :)

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** The area **between** $f_n(x)$ and $f_{n+1}(x)$ is $n^{-1}(n+1)^{-1}$.